# Elasticsearch river - no _meta document found after 5 attempts

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using elasticsearch version 1.3.0. when I create a river using wikipedia plugin version 2.3.0 as thus

```
PUT _river/my_river/_meta -d 
{
  "type" : "wikipedia",
   "wikipedia" : {
        "url" : "http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "wikipedia",
        "type" : "wiki",
        "bulk_size" : 1000,
        "max_concurrent_bulk" : 3
    }
}
```

the server responds with this message

```
{
   "_index": "_river",
   "_type": "my_river",
   "_id": "_meta -d",
   "_version": 1,
   "created": true
}
```

however, I don't see the wikipedia documents when I run a search. also, when I restart my server I get  river-routing no _meta document found after 5 attempts

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-d` at the end as it creates a document named `_meta -d` and not `_meta`.

```
PUT _river/my_river/_meta 
{
  "type" : "wikipedia",
   "wikipedia" : {
        "url" : "http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "wikipedia",
        "type" : "wiki",
        "bulk_size" : 1000,
        "max_concurrent_bulk" : 3
    }
}
```